# Using Rules and PHP to insert a record

Tags: rules

I'm using D7 and Rules 7.2.3

My goal is to insert a record into a non-drupal table using rules.

For the rule action I have:

```
    $userid = [entityform:uid];
$entityform-id = [entityform:entityform-id];
$myresult = db_query("INSERT INTO 'btcalarm' (`userid`, `entityform-id`) VALUES (%d, %d)",$userid, $entityform-id);
```

The rule is triggered (it also has a page redirect as the last step) but the record is not inserted and I do not get an error message.

It seems the code should work, but my biggest concern is how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: I have updated my code to use the latest db_query parameters, but I still end up without a record being inserted and no error message.

Updated Code:
$userid = [entityform:uid];
$entityformid = [entityform:entityform-id];
$sql = "test";

$sql_vars = array(
':userid' => $userid,
':formid' => $entityformid,
':sql' => \"$sql\"
);
 
$myquery = "INSERT INTO 'btcalarm' (`userid`, `entityform-id`, `sql`) VALUES (:userid, :formid, :sql)";

$myresult = db_query($myquery, $sql_vars);

return $myresult;

Comment: By 'non-drupal' table, you don't mean that this table is in another database, do you?  You just mean that this is a table in your default drupal database, but it's just a table you've created rather than one that drupal has created an uses, right?